# Filter features by zoom level of map

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

This is what I am trying to do in Mapbox GL JS (I am new to it): I have a spatial dataset of US cities. Each city has a ranking attribute (1-5). At the default zoom level, I want only the major cities (rank 1) to be visible. As the user gradually zooms in, I want the cities to appear based on their rank (2,3,4,5). This way, only when the user is at the max zoom level can even the smallest cities (rank 5) be visible.

I appreciate any help!

Comment: You should check out [Turf.Js](http://turfjs.org/)

Answer (score 1):

In the Mapbox style specification (filter property on layer object [documentation](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/layers/)) you can filter the features in the US Cities spatial dataset like so:

```
{
  "id": "layer.us-cities,
  ...
  "filter": [
    ">=", ["zoom"],
      ["match", ["get", "rank"],
      1,  // rank
      10, // minimum zoom level
      2,  // etc.
      15,
      3,
      18,
      4,
      20,
      23  // fallback for ranks > 4
    ]
  ]
}
```

The filter consists of 2 parts:

1. The expression to compare the map's current zoom level against
2. The minimum zoom level needed for a city (vector tile feature) of a specific rank

For example: let's say the map's current zoom level is 17. Features with rank 1 (minimum zoom level 10) and rank 2 (min. zoom level 15) will be displayed on the map. From rank 3 onwards the minimum zoom level is at least 18 for which the equation mapZoomLevel >= "city zoom level by rank" doesn't satisfy.

Answer (score -1):

```
filter={[
      "all",
      [
        "match",
        ["get", "level"],
        ["2", "3", "4", "5"],
        [">", ["zoom"], 12.1],
        ["<=", ["zoom"], 16],
      ],
    ]}
```

Comment: This is nonsense. First of all "filter" is an array not an object. Secondly the match expression makes no sense check out: https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/expressions/#match

Comment: Thank you for reminding me. I forgot to add. This is based on the syntax of react

Comment: react is Javascript is Mapbox GL Js? So no difference in the api of Mapbox I suppose!?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).